# Why 'Hunterian' rather than 'Hunter' in the museum at Glasgow University?

Tags: writing-style

On a recent visit to Glasgow, I found myself wondering why the Hunterian Museum (rather than Hunter Museum) and why Andersonian Library (rather than Anderson Library): why this stylistic preference?

Comment: Names are names. You can name anything any way you like, and there is no rhyme or reason to them. Thus, we have the Renwick Gallery within the Smithsonian Institution, yet a short walk away, Columbian College within the George Washington University.

Comment: Another example would be the Bodleian Library at Oxford (named after Sir Thomas Bodley).  Suspect the English style is modeled after Latin grammar (just a guess tho).

Comment: Ask the museum. Ask the library.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this reflects a historical practice of modifying the ending of a proper name by adding ‘ian’ to make an adjective out of it. As has already been mentioned there is the *Bodleian* library at Oxford, and there is alse also the *Ashmolean* museum (named after Ashmole), the *Taylorian* Institute (after Taylor) and the *Sheldonian* Theatre (after Sheldon). Both universities are very old as are the buildings mentioned (Oxford is the oldest, but Glasgow, founded in 1451, is the fourth oldest in Britain).

As Latin was widely used in universities at the time these buildings were founded (and, more recently, my own degree ceremony at Oxford was conducted in Latin) the original documents would have been in Latin. Perhaps the construction of a Latin forms (e.g. Bodleianensis) influenced the English usage. (@AllInOne also makes this point in a comment.)

That said, the *Radcliffe* Camera at Oxford was built to house the Radcliffe Collection, and is *not* referred to as the ‘Radcliffian’. Likewise, the two halls named after Hunter in Glasgow University (mainly used for examinations) are known as the *Hunter Halls*.

Perhaps from these examples one might suppose that the modified (adjectival) form of the name sticks if the noun it qualifies is omitted in general speech (in Glasgow University we generally talk about ‘the Hunterian’ and omit the ‘Museum’), whereas it is shortened to (or retained as) the simple name if the noun is included. No doubt there are exceptions — usage is usage. (However, it could be that the vowel/consonant combination in ‘Radcliffian’ would sound odd.)

Another practice was to use the possessive form of the person’s name, rather than add ‘ian’. Thus there is *Hutcheson’s Hall (or Hospital)* in Glasgow (built between 1802 and 1805), and several Scottish public  — i.e. private fee-paying — schools, e.g. *George Watson’s College* (1741), and *George Heriot’s School* (1628) in Edinburgh, and *Alan Glen’s School* (1853) in Glasgow.

One can see the historical change in usage in relation to a building (now in Glasgow University) that I generally refer to as *The Anderson College*  (after John Anderson). This was previously referred to as *Anderson’s College* (and still is to some extent), but was originally known as The [*Andersonian*](http://www.theglasgowstory.com/image/?inum=TGSE00394).

Comment: I haven't only included one citation, but could add links to web pages relating to specific buildings I mention. As I was an undergraduate at Oxford University and work at Glasgow University, I am the source of contemporary usage in Glasgow and usage in the latter half of the 20th century in Oxford. I think this is valid. Many web references people provide are just repititions without any source given.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, names are names. We are all familiar with American Express and The Ignatian Press. It would seem to me to be nitpicking to question why the ian or an suffix is attached other than to honour the association or to reflect a modality. 'Albert' can just as easily attribute one of his habits by adding that suffix to his name and saying "It's an Albertian thing".

Comment: I'm not familiar with "The Ignatian Press" - I've never heard of it.  Please clarify.